# Using random value generator within if/else statement in Field Calculator in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, random

My task is to populate empty cells of the field `"NUMBER"` with random values (interval 1-50) in all feature classes while iterating through Geodatabase in the Modelbuilder.

Here is the code:

NUMBER=

```
myCalc(!NUMBER!)
```

Code Block:

```py
import random

def myCalc(NUMBER):
    if NUMBER is None or NUMBER=='' or NUMBER==' ':
        return random.randint(1,50)
    else:
        return NUMBER
```

[image: Model and expression]

Also, I need to say, that the `"NUMBER"` field is (and must be) a string one. After completion of the iteration (lasts only 0,16 seconds) nothing changes. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your field is a text format, you should return a string:

```
import random

def myCalc(NUMBER):
    if NUMBER is None or NUMBER=='' or NUMBER==' ':
        return str(random.randint(1,50))
    else:
        return NUMBER
```

Comment: Calculate Field attempts implicit type conversion so adding an explicit type conversion won't change the result.  If the OP's code isn't working, it is something different than converting to a string.